# routing to Directory outside / Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i installed a project on my www folder in wamp , but when i add new route and try to get it wil the browser i got page not found , i copied all laravel 4 files to local folder exclude publi folder and i put its content on www , and try my route , i got the same error :

the routes :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

when i get to " localhost " , it works fine but when i get to " localhost/about" i got page not found and i modified paths and index files and same issue

Comment: you can simply make the virtaulhost and it can work !!

Comment: @Hardy Mathew how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable `rewrite_mod` :

> Open the httpd.conf file and search for

```
"rewrite"
```

, then remove

```
"#"
```

at the starting of the line,so the line looks like.

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

then restart the wamp.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that `rewrite_mod` is disabled in your Apache installation.

Try enabling it. [Here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: when i use " a2enmod rewrite" in my cmd i got "'a2enmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." ??

Comment: Which web-server do you use: nginx, apache, built-in?

Comment: I guess you're using Apache. Make sure you created an alias for a2enmod.
You could have tried the 2nd answer in my link as well. I didn't want to repeat the answer as it has been already asked before.